# Extracting information from DHCP client list

Tags: cmd, dhcp

Usually when I access my router settings by entering the IP Adress in my browser I can access a list of all clients connected to my network. Is there a way to retrieve this information somehow and export it to a .txt file or to Excel? I tried some CMD code but in vain.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [arp](https://ss64.com/nt/arp.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stephan. I did try arp -a but it doesn't seem to show the IP Addresses of the same deviced in the browser client list

Comment: `arp` does only show "known" members. You should delete the arp cache `arp -d` (to clear entries for clients previously online, but now offline) , then `ping` your IP range to fill that cache again (with only currently online clients).

Comment: The following line works quite efficient: `@(for /l %i in (1,1,255) DO @start /min ping 192.168.1.%i -n 1) && @timeout 10 >nul && @arp -a|find "dynamìc"`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Stephan I finally did it. I used your code followed by "arp -a > log.txt & notepad.exe log.txt" and it exported the data to text file. Much appreciated. You should put your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [arp](https://ss64.com/nt/arp.html) command. It lists addresses, that are known to the computer. Which basically means, "there was some communication to/from this address since last reset (explicit reset or reboot)". But it doesn't tell you, whether the address is currently reachable. So to get reachable addresses, you have to delete arp's cache, force communication with every address (a ping is sufficient) and then show the cache:

```
@echo off
arp -d
(for /l %%i in (1,1,255) DO start /min ping 192.168.1.%%i -n 1) & timeout 10 >nul 
arp -a | find "dynamic"
```

The `timeout` gives time to finish the `ping`s and for `arp` to build it's cache data.

Be sure to adapt the base address (`192.168.1.`) to your needs. If you use a non-English version of Windows, you also have to adapt the string `dynamic`.

The `start /min` makes the `ping`s quite effective by running them parallel.

Note: some computers/devices may not respond to `ping`, so they would be missing in the list.

*Bonus line:*

```
for /f %%a in ('arp -a^|find "dynam"') do for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=[] " %%b in ('ping -a -n 1 %%a^|find "["') do echo %%c %%b
```

(again, that's for the English version. Adapt the tokens for other languages; for a German Windows, it's `tokens=5,6`)